# Remove marker in Google Maps Api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using this function to add a new marker (and polyline) to a map:

```
 function addMarker(location) {

    path = poly.getPath();
    path.push(location);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        icon:'location.png',
        title: poly.inKm() + ' km',
        map: map
    });
    markersArray.push(marker);
}
```

How can I remove the last marker (for implementing undo)?

Best regards ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[RemovingOverlays](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#RemovingOverlays)

```
markersArray[markersArray.length-1].setMap(null);
```

... for path:

```
path = poly.getPath();
path.pop();
```

[PolylineOptions](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#PolylineOptions), [MVCArray](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MVCArray).

Comment: Hi,thanks. This works great for the markers, but I cannot remove the last point of the polyline. Best regards ...

Answer (score 0):

Last Marker is at the index of `markersArray.length -1` so...

`markersArray[markersArray.length-1].setMap(null);`