# Google Maps v3 - Trying to delete a marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove marker in Google Maps Api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726049/remove-marker-in-google-maps-api-v3)

I'm trying to give users access to close the infowindow by hitting the "X", which in turn lets them get rid of the marker as well.  I thought the code below would work but it doesn't.  Does anyone have any suggestions.

```
function addLaunch() {  
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map    
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "closeclick", function() {
        map.removeOverlay(marker2);
            });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `removeOverlay()` method is from the API V2. in V3 you'd use:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "closeclick", function() {
    marker2.setMap(null);
});
```